# Multiple monitors at different resolutions

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

I'm running a Dell XPS 13 9350 that has a resolution of 3200x1800, and then I have an external display running 1920x1080, all of a sudden a few months ago, windows and dialogs on the external display suddenly started to appear weirdly.

Dialogs would appear super large and depending on the window, the close/maximize/minimize buttons would get stretched.

Here's a screenshot of my desktops in a vertical stack (1920x1080 is on top)

Note how the chrome window on the top monitor appears to have been cut off at the top of the screen, and how the buttons in the top right have been stretched, and lastly how the chrome window very slightly stretched too far at the bottom underneath the task bar. (You may need to open the image in another tab and zoom in)

Then the image below is the "save file" dialog on the same monitor within Chrome (this problem extends to all dialogs from any application)

And lastly, all my drivers are up to date.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

[image: Desktop screenshot]

Oversized Dialog:
[image: Oversized dialog]

Comment: Which one is your main display, and what happens when you switch them?

Comment: The bottom one is my main display (the laptop screen). When I switch them, the same effect happens on the top display